# Reproduzir vídeos em todos os dispositivos

Tags: android, html5

Não consigo fazer com que os vídeos de um site sejam reproduzidos em android e em outros dispositivos.

Usei o Freemake Video Converter para transformar meu vídeo em todos os formatos para HTML5. Então já funciona em todos os navegadores, nos computadores, porém faço os testes e ele não roda em nenhum dos meus dispositivos; tablet e nem em celulares android. Mas fiz testes com estes dispositivos e entrei em outros sites e os vídeos que lá têm rodam nos meus dispositivos perfeitamente. Então óbvio que estou errando em algo.

Onde estou errando? ou o que esta faltando para conseguir que o vídeo seja visualizado em celulares?

```
<video id="video_principal" id=0 controls>
<source src="videos/video1.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
<source src="videos/video1.webm" type='video/webm' >
<source src="videos/video1.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<p>Desculpe, mas não foi possível carregar o vídeo.</p>
</video>
```

Comment: Que erro ocorre? Aparece a mensagem `Desculpe, mas não foi possível carregar o vídeo.`? Ou o video fica travado?

Comment: Não aparece erro nenhum @guilherme, nem a mensagem de erro da tag video aparece. A tela fica preta. Será que é que um video de 14 megas e grande demais para ser reproduzido em celulares? e ele não esta sendo carregado ou esta em espera?